# android: DatePicker's Listener doesn't work

Tags: android, datepicker

My code is as follow. What I want is that the title changes according to the date I have chosen.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private TimePicker timePicker;
    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private Calendar cal;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        setTitle(year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "-" + hour + "-" + minute);

        datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

        datePicker.init(year, month, day, new OnDateChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                setTitle(year + "-" + monthOfYear + "-" + dayOfMonth);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

When I run it in the simulator and change the date, the title never changes.

Comment: You should probably add the setTitle method so we can exclude that from the list of possible problems.

Comment: setTitle is a method of Activity.

Comment: Try:  ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setTitle(year + "-" + monthOfYear + "-" + dayOfMonth); instead of setTitle(...);

Comment: you can use the Dialog that is the best option for DatePickre.

Comment: siliar thing here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507394/android-date-picker-listener-doesnt-work-more-than-one-time

Comment: @sarbjot I don't want to use the Dialog. I want to know why the DatePicker cannot work correctly. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @AtulOHolic I don't think this is the same kind of problem.

Comment: @Rami I use API Level 21. There's no ActionBar.

Comment: You use android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity?

Comment: Can you try putting a Log or Toast inside onDateChanged so that we know if the issue is with the DatePickerListener or the setTitle?

Comment: @Rami Yes, no ActionBar

Answer (score 0):

The Date picker Dialog Example that is fully working for me:

```
//declaration of DatePickerDialog//
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
//intailizing the datePicakerDialog//
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),
                Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH), Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

//DatePickerDialog listerner

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int years, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
                datePickerDialog.updateDate(
                        Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar
                                .getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH), Calendar
                                .getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            }
        }
    };

//Seting date on dismising thedate picker//

datePickerDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                if (!isDateSet) {
                    datePickerDialog.updateDate(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                                    }
            }
        });
```

I hope this code will help you out from this problem

Comment: I don't want to use the DatePickerDialog. I want to know why the DatePicker doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I add two Logs, one outside, another inside.

```
   Log.i("tag", "Outside");
    datePicker.init(year, month, day, new OnDateChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("tag", "Go inside onDateChanged");
            setTitle(year + "-" + monthOfYear + "-" + dayOfMonth);
        }
    });
```

then I run it in the simulator, I get the result as follow.
[image]

No matter how I change the date from the simulator, there is no Log Infomation saying "Go inside onDateChanged".